# curl command from fabfile is not working

Tags: python, unix, curl, jenkins

I have a curl command to register some services with an URL and I am calling it in python function which is written in jenkins. I am executiong this in jenkins and my code is as below. I am providing sudo password with an environment variable in the python script itself.

```
def remote_deploy():
    sudo('curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d \'{"Name":"CSR_TOOLBOX","Address":"52.48.24.244","Port":81}\' http://consul.service.consul:8500/v1/agent/service/register')
```

I am always getting invalid syntax error even though i tried many options. Please help me.

Comment: You need to show exactly how you're running this, and a log of the output; see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: writeFile file: 'fabfile.py', text: """
    from __future__ import with_statement
    from fabric.api import *
    from fabric.contrib.console import confirm
    import os
   env.sudo_prompt = "[sudo] password for " + env.user + ":"
   env.use_shell=False
  
   def remote_deploy():
   sudo('curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d \'{"Service":{"Name":"CSR_TOOLBOX","Address":"52.48.24.244","Port":81}}\' http://consul.service.consul:8500/v1/agent/service/register')} calling this function remote_deploy() from another shell in jenkins.

Comment: You can (and should) edit your question to include this, in a properly formatted code block. But most importantly, include how it's called, and what the Jenkins build log shows.

Comment: You can also run `sh 'cat fabfile.py'` during the build to ensure that the file contains what you expect.